# Printing Loops of random numbers

Tags: loops, random, printing, numbers

Can someone explain why program 1 prints only one random number repeatedly? And while the program 2 below it prints 100 random numbers? Also, is there was to edit program 1 to do what program 2 did?

Program 1

```
public class RandomComparison {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        int rnd = (int) Math.random() * 6 + 1;

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        System.out.print(rnd);
        }

    }


}
```

Program 2

```
public class RandomPractice {
    public static void main (String[] args){
        int roll;
        String msg = "Here are 100 random rolls of the dice:";
        System.out.println(msg);

        for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
            roll = randomInt(1, 6);
            System.out.print(roll);
        }
    }

    public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
        int result = (int) (Math.random()*(6) + low);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you are printing same variable `rnd`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first method, you're retrieving a random value once and printing that single value 100 times. The second method is generating a random number 100 times and printing it with each iteration.

```
int rnd = (int) Math.random() * 6 + 1;//grabbed only once

for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
    System.out.print(rnd);//printing `rnd` 100 times
}



for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
        roll = randomInt(1, 6);//calling for a new random number with each iteration, then printing it
        System.out.print(roll);
}
```

And to use your `randomInt` method correctly:

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high){
    int result = (int) (Math.random()*(high) + low);//replace `6` with the parameter `high`
    return result;
}
```

To fix your first method to have it run the same as your second method:

```
public class RandomComparison {

   public static void main(String[] args){

       for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
           System.out.print((int)(Math.random()* 6) + 1);//prints out a random number with every iteration
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes a lot of sense. How I do get it to make a rnd 100 times? I tried to move the initializing statement inside the loop but I still only get 1 number repeated 100 times

Comment: Are you asking how to generate a random number 100 times and print each random number? If so, the second for loop in your code above, accompanied with your `randomInt` method accomplishes this. You just have to use your method parameters correctly. I'll put this in my answer.

Comment: Yes to your first question. I was just wondering if there was another way of generating a random number 100 times other than creating another class. I felt like there was a simpler way than having to do that.

Comment: Do you mean creating two programs to try and accomplish the same feat? Or a second method - in this case `randomInt()`?

Comment: I mean is there a quick fix to program 1 that does the same thing as program 2?

Comment: Sure. I'll put that in the answer too. :)

Comment: :) lol thanks. I saw that you can just use the high value and it still produces the random numbers within that range. That's why I put just 6. That might lead to some anomalies but it seems to work.

Comment: Glad it works! Please make sure to check this as the correct answer as it will help us both out with reputation, helps the community, and in the future if you have further questions, people will be more inclined to answer knowing you mark the correct answers. :)